# How do I get the current time in a special TimeZone with TIdDayTimeServer?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

How do i get current time from different time zones with **TIdDayTimeServer**?

for example I set **TIdDayTimeServer** TimeZone to **EST** or **BST** and i want show the date and time on a label.

thanx.

Comment: Do you *have* to use TIdDayTimeServer?

Comment: yes i use TIdDayTimeServer.

Comment: What EXACTLY are you trying to accomplish? To display the Android device's own date/time, or to query a remote server for its date/time?

Answer (score 1):

That is not how the [`DAYTIME`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc867) protocol works, and thus are not how `TIdDayTimeServer` and `TIdDayTimeUDPServer` are implemented.  The server's local date/time with the specified `TimeZone` property appended to the end of it is sent to the client as soon as it connects to the server. There is no way to ask the server for a specific timezone.

The same applies to the [`TIME`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc868) protocol (the `TIdTimeServer` and `TIdTimeUDPServer` components) as well.  The local date/time is returned to the client, just in a binary format whereas `DAYTIME` returns the local date/time in a string format.

You need to find another solution to your problem.